# Extract and list the most occuring objects in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have an app where the user posts reviews of albums. I want to list the top ten most reviewed albums on the site. So far I have gotten this much: (the reviews are called pins)

```
<%= Pin.group(:album).count.sort %>
```

Which will give me an array with results like this:

> [["Aladdin Sane", 2], ["An Awesome Wave", 2], ["Bon Iver", 1], ["Helplessness Blues", 3], ["Hot Sauce Committee Part Two", 1], ["House Of Balloons", 1], ["James Blake", 1], ["Kaputt", 1], ["No Color", 2], ["Out Of The Game", 1], ["Overgrown", 1], ["Paul Simon", 1], ["People, Hell, and Angels", 1], ["Strange Mercy", 1], ["The Harrow & The Harvest", 1], ["The Hunter", 1], ["The Idler Wheel", 1], ["The King Of Limbs", 1], ["Up All Night", 1], ["Yoshimi Battles The Pink Robots", 2], ["Yuck", 2], ["undun", 1]]

Do I need to write  whole new method to accomplish this, or are there just some array methods that I'm not aware of that will accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Pin.group(:album).count.sort_by{|k, v| -v}.take(10)
```

Comment: That works to list them as an array, but I'm looking to call pin.album and list each album name.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but it seems better to limit the rows returned by the database.

```
Pin.group(:album).limit(10).order('count(*) desc')
```